# sql distinct statement not working in powershel script

Tags: sql, powershell

I am trying to run the following sql command on a powershell script:
I set the following as a variable:

```ps
$DBSUM =     select x.[example 1], y.example2, z.example3
from (select count (distinct valueA) AS "example 1"
      from dbo.table1
     ) as x,
     (select count (distinct ValueB) AS "example2"
      from dbo.table2
     ) as y,
     (select count (distinct ValueC) AS "example3"
      from dbo.table3
     ) as z
```

after some other commands, i have the following:

```ps
    $SqlConnectionSUM = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnectionSUM.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = 
    $SQLDB; Integrated Security = True"

    $SqlCmdSUM = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmdSUM.CommandText = $DBSUM
    $SqlCmdSUM.Connection = $SqlConnectionSUM

    $SqlAdapterSUM = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapterSUM.SelectCommand = $SqlCmdSUM

    $DataSetSUM = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $null = $SqlAdapterSUM.Fill($DataSetSUM) 
    $DataSetSUM.Tables[0] | select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, 
   HasErrors, ItemArray,Table | ConvertTo-Html -Head $HtmlHead | Out-File 
   "$PSScriptRoot\filelocation\example.html"
```

The above command works perfectly in SQL, but when I run on my powershell I get the error:

```ps
    + ... .example3 from (select count (distinct ValueA) AS "example1 ...
    +                                                            ~~~~~~
    Unexpected token 'example' in expression or statement.
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Please can anyone advise?

Thank you.

Comment: SQL cannot be used directly in PowerShell. There has to be some layer around it, be it a command line tool or some .NET objects. And that part is missing in your post. [Edit] it and include a [example].

Comment: Why the space in `example 1` (and not in example2 or example3) ??

Comment: Have your tried to change `AS "example 1"` to `AS example1`   (Leave out the double quotes, and the space in the alias) ?

Comment: Do not use quoted identifiers unless they arereally needed for command-line reporting (which is very rare case), because they make your code more error prone.

Comment: Theo - the space on Example 1 was on purpose as i had on my script a header with space. Thank you all for your comments, it helped me to identify the issue with teh spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Luuk and Astentx for your replies.

I have now working ok, the issue was the `"` and spaces on `example 1`

I replaced the spaces with `_` and removed the `"` and t works absolutely fine.

Here is the result:

```ps
$DBSUM =     select x.example_1, y.example2, z.example3
from (select count (distinct valueA) AS example_1
      from dbo.table1
     ) as x,
     (select count (distinct ValueB) AS example2
      from dbo.table2
     ) as y,
     (select count (distinct ValueC) AS example3
      from dbo.table3
     ) as z
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You can use [language identifiers](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) after the beginning of code blocks to make [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) more appropriate. Like this: ```lang-ps